# FadeIn & FadeOut with CSS 3?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I need to make a smooth nice transition to show/hide a text depending if the top element have a class "error" or not.

But i really cant get this to work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/qd9wq/1/

Would really appreciate any kind of help.

I've got my idea from http://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html#test3. 
But i dont want to use 2 kind of classes.

Edit: Solved problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qd9wq/78/

Comment: Having looked at the fiddle, I'm seeing a lot of `content1 is not defined` error messages when clicking the buttons.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is that you're having?

Comment: I cant get the first transition to work smoothly. The "FadeIn" doesnt have any fading.. It's just popup after 2 seconds. But the "FadeOut" fade outs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `transition-delay` to this class:

```
fieldset.error > ul > li {
  margin-top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition-delay:0s;
  -moz-transition-delay:0s;
  -o-transition-delay:0s;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qd9wq/92/)

You can also remove all the `!important`, they are not needed.

Comment: Sorry, but that didnt do the trick either. Thanks anyway

My friend solved it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qd9wq/78/

Comment: But it still use javascript. Why not to use crossbrowser `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? It's working in the example? You need to add the transition to all browsers.

Comment: Sorry Niclas. Your solution work as well. Had to restart my browser. Cause it didnt work the first time. Thanks for the help!